# Can you add an event listener on a p tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if adding an event listener onto a p tag was possible. I was thinking of having it listen for a keypress when a certain paragraph pops up. I am making a math html/javascript game and the event would reshuffle some problems when the player gets the win text and the presses space for example. I don't want it to be able to be pressed until that message pops up which is why I want to attach it to the p tag. It would activate some js code for reshuffling.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just allow the keypress after a flag gets set by the popup action? There's no reason to put it on that `<p>`--it sounds more like you want a page-wide keypress handler that's valid only under certain circumstances.

Comment: It's possible, but follow Daves advice. Have the function that shows the win text also set a flag or add the event listener to the entire document. Then any spacebar press after the win text shows will work, no matter if the keypress was inside the <p> or not.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm aiming for. I understand the flag but how could I use that to activate a keypress handler?